# Is there always a natural correspondence between the ends of a geodesic space $X$, and the connected components of $\partial_\infty X$?

Tags: metric-spaces, hyperbolic-geometry, gromov-hyperbolic-spaces

For a metric space $X$, let $\partial_\infty X$ denote the (Gromov) boundary at infinity of $X$. The following fact appears as an exercise in Bridson-Haefliger's standard text [1, p. 430].

> Let $X$ be a geodesic space that is proper and hyperbolic. Then the natural map $\partial_\infty X \to Ends(X)$ is continuous and the fibres of this map are precisely the connected components of $\partial_\infty X$.

Thus, if I'm not mistaken, we have a natural 1-1 correspondence between the ends of $X$ and the connected components of $\partial_\infty X$.

This fact seems quite intuitive, so much so that the condition that $X$ be hyperbolic seems almost unnecessary. My question is, if we relax this condition, does this statement continue to be true, or even make sense anymore?

Edit: For convenience I add the relevant definitions below. Since we are working with spaces more general than hyperbolic, we have the following definition of the Gromov boundary. The following definition is taken from Section 8.3 of [2]

**Definition.** Let $X$ be a (quasi-)geodesic metric space. Then the Gromov boundary of $X$ is defined as
$$
\partial X := \{\gamma : [0,\infty) \to X : \text{$\gamma$ is a quasi-geodesic ray}\} / \sim,
$$
where we say that $\gamma \sim \gamma'$ if there exists some $c > 0$ such that (the image of) $\gamma$ is contained within the $c$-neighbourhood of $\gamma'$, and vice versa, i.e. they have finite Hausdorff distance.

We define a topology on $\partial X$ through convergence of sequences. We say that a sequence $(x_n)_n \in \partial X^{\mathbb N}$ converges to $x \in \partial X$ if there exists a sequence of quasi-geodesic rays $(\gamma_n)_n$ such that each $\gamma_n \in x_n$, and some $\gamma \in x$, such that every subsequence of $(\gamma_n)$ contains a subsequence that converges (uniformly on compact subsets of $[0,\infty)$) to $\gamma$.

---

[1] Bridson, M. R., & Haefliger, A. (2013). Metric spaces of non-positive curvature (Vol. 319). Springer Science & Business Media.

[2] Löh, C. (2017). Geometric group theory. Springer International Publishing AG.

Comment: What is your definition of Gromov-boundary if a space is not hyperbolic? (I am guessing that you would use equivalence classes of geodesic rays. But what about the topology on the boundary?) Also, likely, you will have to assume that the space is proper.

Comment: @MoisheKohan For the sake of this question, we'll define the Gromov boundary via quasi-geodesic rays, as is done in Section 8.3 of Löh, 2017. I think this is the most reasonable definition for general geodesic $X$.

Comment: Please, edit your question to make your definition clear, especially, as I said, the topology on the boundary. As for your reference: Not everybody has access to that book.

Comment: Will do, thanks

Comment: Good. Then the answer is negative, even for 1-ended planar graphs of bounded valence where $\partial X$ is homeomorphic to the Cantor set. Could you find an example yourself given this hint?